# Нормализация бд по 3нф

Tags: база-данных, нормализация-данных

Нормально ли нормализована бд по 3 форме? Что можно улучшить?
[image: бд]

Comment: А почему у поставщика первичный ключ varchar(45)?

Comment: Да, почему у поставщика нет нормального справочника с id, почему во все таблицы таскается его название фактически? И ещё я бы количество товара и поставщика убрал из справочника товаров. Не знаю как это объяснить, может если один товар будет от разных поставщиков или на разных складах, например, лежать, тогда это будет объяснимо, почему нужно вынести наружу. В общем, количество и поставщик - это не свойство самого товара, не нужно это в его справочнике, я думаю.